# How to tell mongodb library (node.js) to reconnect?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following minimal code tries to connect to mongod. It works great, but if the db will go offline before the script will be executed, it will exit and will never connect. I want it to try to connect until success.

```
var http = require('http')
  , mongodb = require('mongodb');

var options = {
    {
        uri_decode_auth: true,
        numberOfRetries: 1000,
        db: {
            numberOfRetries: 1000,
            retryMiliSeconds: 5000,
            bufferMaxEntries: 0
        },
        server: {
            auto_reconnect: true,
            socketOptions: {
                connectTimeoutMS: 5000,
            },
            reconnectTries: 1000,
            reconnectInterval: 5000,
        }
};

mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname', options, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('failure');
        return;
    }
    console.log('success');
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    }).listen(80);
});
```

Comment: auto_reconnect: true ?

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269345/handle-lost-connection-to-mongo-db-from-nodejs

Comment: auto_reconnect is true, updated my question